# Android - How to add dummy items to ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'd like to add a dummy item (or 2) at the end of a ListView to make the final item easier to access. Padding the ListView will limit the entire ListView which is not what I am looking for. Is there a way to add one which is not clickable and is only there to lift up the final item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know exactly what you want.

Do this in your layout:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false" />
```

clipToPadding when set to **false** will add that space in the end of your ListView if you have added padding. Its default value is set to **true** and that causes the padding to stay annoyingly always at the bottom of the view. You know what I mean.

Comment: I was going to. But it didn't let me because it's too early